Azure DevOps REST from using Device Flow from rich client registration expectation
I have an application which uses "Device Flow" to authenticate with "Azure DevOps".  The application successfully uses the REST API to access data.  It all works great.
I want to make the application available to outside organizations.  I'm not sure what someone outside of our domain needs to do to use this application.   The app currently has hard-coded the client-id and tenant id, which I can externalize to a config file.
Does this mean my customers have to register my app in their "App Registrations" section of their Azure Portal of their domain?  If so, is there a way I can simplify this for them by giving them a configuration file that they can import into the Azure Portal, to ensure they don't make a mistake creating an App Registration.
When I install other tools that use Device Flow for authentication, such as JetBrains Rider, I notice in the plug-in source code here ( https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-intellij.git ) it uses the ClientID "97877f11-0fc6-4aee-b1ff-febb0519dd00"
which looks like it's from Microsoft.  I don't know what that is. Is that something generic that can be used by other third-party products such as mine?  Or is that something special for JetBrains?
And if someone were to use JetBrains, would they need to create an app registration in their Azure Portal?  And if not, does that mean that Azure approves the above ClientID automatically?
I don't see any instructions in JetBrains Rider where the customer has to register the application with their Azure domain.


Does this mean my customers have to register my app in their "App Registrations" section of their Azure Portal of their domain?

No, as mentioned in the doc, you can only add a service principal for the tenant your organization is connected to.
The app registration process involves creating a unique client ID and tenant ID specific to their Azure AD tenant, even you create a multi-tenant application, when accessing target devops resource, still need to use target tenant and client id, you can check the link here for the details.
The ClientID 97877f11-0fc6-4aee-b1ff-febb0519dd00 used by JetBrains Rider is a public application registered by Microsoft. It can also be found in link here and here. However, it is specific to applications registered by Microsoft or other trusted providers.
